# Sqlite outer union

Tags: sqlite

Does Sqlite support OUTER UNION?
I have tried it in my code but something seems wrong. UNION alone works fine.

```
q =''
if table1:
    q = f'''
        SELECT * FROM {table1} '''
if table2:
    q += f'''
        OUTER UNION 
        SELECT * FROM {table2}
    '''

q+=";"
```

Comment: No. OUTER UNION is not even standard sql.

Comment: thank you! I need to apply outer union. do you have any suggestions to do so ?

Comment: You will have to enumerate all the columns of the 2 tables and also for the non-existing columns supply nulls. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Thank you very much! that is actually doable. I appreciate your help.